# OpenFile Dialog MS Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, openfiledialog

I followed the suggestion by Cody Gray about halfway down the page in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746938/is-there-an-open-file-dialog-for-access-2010-64bit) but I'm having no luck.

Unless I'm missing something, this is supposed to allow me to navigate from Access, using the Windows API Dialog Box, to the relevant folder and open a file, no? I'm trying to open a Word doc which has a Mail Merge coming back to the same Access Db. I needed the dialog because there are multiple files that may be selected at different times.

I added all the suggested code and while the process runs without error, when I get to the final step, the selected file doesn't open. Nothing happens.

I realize this is not much help without an error message. Any thoughts nonetheless?

Comment: What do you have as your final step --- the step which is supposed to open the selected file?  As far as I can see from the code you linked, all it does it select a file, but doesn't actually open the file.

Comment: My code is exactly as in the example on the thread. so my last step is      `Dim strFileToOpen As String
    strFileToOpen = OpenFile("Choose a file to open", strFilter, 0, "C:\")`

Comment: Really I should say that is the last "action" piece of code. Following that are the MsgBox parts

Comment: Nevermind! You asking the question @HansUp prompted me to look for what was missing and I have what I need. Thanks!

Comment: I submitted an answer anyway.  Sorry it was too late to help you.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the situation, you have code which uses a string variable named `strFileToOpen` to hold the path to a Ms Word document.  And now you want to open that file in Word.

You can use the `FollowHyperlink` method.

```
Application.FollowHyperlink strFileToOpen
```

Look at the Access help topic for that method.  It offers other options you may wish to use.

Also I suggest you look at the help topic for *FileDialog Object*.  It is simpler than the Windows APi method in the code you linked.